# How to infer this equivalence from the given set of axioms in propositional calculus: Θ→¬Ψ ∨ Φ ⊢ (¬Ψ ∨ Θ →¬Φ ∧ Ψ) → ¬Θ

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have an assignment to derive the propositional formula $\Theta\to \neg \Psi \vee \Phi \vdash (\neg \Psi \vee\Theta \to \neg \Phi \wedge \Psi) \to\neg \Theta$ from the system of
axioms and lemmas (previously derived rules from axioms), but I am deadly stuck not knowing what to begin with. I have looked up all the relevant notions to the assignment, but still don't know how to move ahead what steps are due to be done first. Please, enlighten me giving me a push! These are the axioms and rules:

Axiom A1. $\Phi\to\left(\Psi\to\Phi\right)$

Axiom A2. $\left(\Phi\to\Psi\right)\to\left(\left(\Phi\to\left(\Psi\to\Theta\right)\right)\to\left(\Phi\to\Theta\right)\right)$

Axiom A3 $\Phi \wedge \Psi \to \Phi$

Axiom A4. $\Phi \wedge \Psi \to \Psi$

Axiom A5. $\left(\Phi\to\Psi\right)\to\left(\left(\Phi\to\Theta\right)\to\left(\Phi\to\Psi \wedge \Theta\right)\right)$

Axiom A6. $\Phi\to\Phi \vee \Psi$

Axiom A7. $\Psi\to\Phi \vee \Psi$

Axiom A8. $\left(\Phi\to\Theta\right)\to\left(\left(\Psi\to\Theta\right)\to\left(\Phi \vee \Psi\to\Theta\right)\right)$

Axiom A9. $\left.\left(\Phi\to\Psi\right)\to\left(\left(\Phi\to\neg \Psi\right)\to\neg \Phi\right)\right)$

Axiom A10. $\neg\neg \Phi\to\Phi$

---

Lemma 1. $\vdash \Phi \to \Phi$

Lemma 2 . $\Phi, \Psi \vdash \Phi \wedge \Psi$

Lemma 3. $\Phi\to\Psi \vdash \neg \Psi\to\neg\Phi$

Lemma 4 $\Phi\to\Psi, \Psi\to\Theta \vdash \Phi\to\Theta$

Lemma 5. $\Phi\vdash \neg\neg\Phi$

Lemma 6 . $\Phi \wedge \neg \Phi \vdash \Psi$  ... where $\Psi$ is any formula

The Deduction Theorem may be used!

Comment: Let me know if I made some type error while editing in MathJax

Comment: There is no need to subscript the conditionals.  Just `\to` will suffice, rather than `_{\to}`

Comment: *Hint*: assume $\Theta$ and use Axiom A9.

Comment: There is a typo on Axiom A8.

Comment: Shouldn't Lemma 4 be "$\Phi\to\Psi, \Psi\to\Theta \vdash \Phi\to\Theta"$?

Comment: Thank you, Mauro ALLEGRANZA, I corrected the typo in Axiom A8 but still unable to use the clue to assume Θ being a perfect novice in the field. What would it be to assume Θ? I can't get the clue because don't understand this.

Comment: I hope that you can use the Deduction Th...

Comment: Rick, yes, exactly, thank you! Corrected. – Errdonald 5 hours ago

Comment: Hilbert-style proofs are useless, and I don't know why people still ask for them as exercises.